# Ajax Rating control in popup

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I am developing a page to display some videos with asp .net fw3.5. The page will display a list of videos with thumbnails. When the user clicks a video thumb i will open a popup and show the video in the popup. There will be a rating control in the video.the user can vote for the video using the ajax rating control. the popup should remain shown after rating control is clicked.

I have done some of the coding but the problem is I cant get the current rating of the rating control without doing a postback. I can make the popup always visible by using an update panel  but if i do so the close button of the modal popupextender doesnt work and i cannot close the modal popup. Here is my related code portion:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="display: none" />      
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" OkControlID="btnOkay"
    TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
    Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="PopupCss">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="mediaplayer">
                    JW Player goes here</div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                        flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
                        file: "<%=videoName %>",
                        image: "<%=videoThumb %>",
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%"
                    });
                </script>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                <div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true">
                </div> 
                <br />
                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%=videoLink%>"
                    data-num-posts="3" data-width="470">
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_2">
                    </a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_4">
                    </a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f61d99d08697325"></script>
                <!-- AddThis Button END -->
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" MaxRating="5" StarCssClass="ratingStar" FilledStarCssClass="ratingStarFilled"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="VideoRatingChanged" EmptyStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty"
                    WaitingStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%=videoId%>' />
                </asp:Rating>
                &nbsp (<%=voteCount%>)
                <br />
                Minder Score:
                <%=minderScore %>
                <br />
                <div class="Controls" style="text-align: left;">
                    <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Kapat" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

How can i manage to have the desired functionality.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to warp it with an `UpdatePanel`

```
<br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" MaxRating="5" StarCssClass="ratingStar" FilledStarCssClass="ratingStarFilled"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="VideoRatingChanged" EmptyStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty"
                    WaitingStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%=videoId%>' />
                </asp:Rating>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

For the part of total vote count, if you like to include it inside the UpdatePanel you need to change it with `asp:literal` controls, and render inside this control the results. So if you like to include this code inside the UpdatePanel, for automatic update them,

```
&nbsp (<%=voteCount%>)
<br />
Minder Score:
<%=minderScore %>
```

you need to write it as

```
&nbsp (<asp:Literal runat="server" id="txtVoteCount" />)
<br />
Minder Score: <asp:Literal runat="server" id="txtMinderScore" />
```

and on code behind place this values.

If you see this sample http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx

and get the source code from the SDK, this is the way is doing it.